# Referencing with GeoIndex

Tags: json, indexing, python-2.x, geo, geopoints

I am new to GeoIndex. Currently I have ~1600 geo-tagged images, I am working with GeoIndex to find all images within a certain radius of my point(or my current location), all is working fine, it is returning the points which match the query. However as each image has a unique URL I need to be able to maintain the link between Geo coordinate and the URL.

For example:

```
def find_distance(index,myLocation,arraySearch,radius):

    myUrlArray = []
    for coords in arraySearch:
        index.add_point(GeoPoint(coords[0],coords[1]))

    for point,distance in index.get_nearest_points(myLocation,radius,'km'):
        print point
```

myLocation is passed in as a paramter as is an array called arraySearch which contains data read from a JSON file in the following format:

```
arraySearch = [(latitudecoordinate,longitudecoordinate,url)]
```

when running the above function I get the following output:

```
Point(54.573307, -5.998721)
Point(54.600225, -5.920579)
Point(54.598671, -5.918605)
Point(54.598671, -5.918605)
Point(54.598671, -5.918605)
Point(54.598671, -5.918605)
Point(54.598671, -5.918605)
Point(54.598671, -5.918605)
Point(54.601469, -5.921652)
Point(54.601493, -5.920901)
```

Ideally I would like:

```
(Point(x,y),URL)
```

thanks in advance!

Edited to correct indentation errors in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you simply need to include the url in the `ref` slot available in the [object structure](https://github.com/gusdan/geoindex/blob/master/geoindex/geo_point.py):

```
def find_distance(index,myLocation,arraySearch,radius):

    myUrlArray = []
    for value in arraySearch:
        index.add_point(GeoPoint(value[0],value[1], ref=value[2]))

    for point,distance in index.get_nearest_points(myLocation,radius,'km'):
        print point, point.ref
```

As the `Point` object doesn't include this attribute in their `__repr__` method, you will need to add it in your `print` statement as above.

Comment: Ah amazing! Thank you very much Héctor!

Comment: You're welcome! Did it work? I'm afraid I didn't tested. Also, I've proposed a change to the Geoindex code based on your question: https://github.com/gusdan/geoindex/pull/2

Comment: Yes! Worked quite nicely! I agree with your proposed change!